# How to make set lite mode for Android Google MapFragment in XML?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) state that the easiest way to create a MapFragment in XML is like so:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If creating a MapFragment in this manner, how do I set lite mode to `true`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, there is a bug when adding a map fragment as a child to a parent container. I solved this by first changing the namespace of the parent container like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Now, the problem is that there is an invalid error flagged in the fragment (`Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment`). The simplest way to overcome this in Android Studio is to add `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix`. This is my completed XML code for the fragment:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    map:liteMode="true"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the xml

```
   <fragment mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraZoom="13"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:liteMode="true"/>
```

In the GoogleMapOptions object

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question I asked.